# mysql INNER_JOIN subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have inherited a MySQL database, that has a table as follows:

```
mysql> describe stock_groups;
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| group  | varchar(5)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| parent | varchar(5)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I run `mysql> select * from stock_groups where`group`='D2';`

I get:

```
mysql> select * from stock_groups where `group`='D2';
+----+-------+------+--------+-------+
| id | group | name | parent | order |
+----+-------+------+--------+-------+
| 79 | D2    | MENS | D      |    51 |
+----+-------+------+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and also i have a table:

```
mysql> describe stock_groups_styles_map;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| group | varchar(5)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| style | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

when I run:

```
mysql> select `group` from stock_groups_styles_map where style='N26';
+-------+
| group |
+-------+
| B1    |
| B11   |
| D2    |
| V2    |
+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

how do i get the `stock_groups.name` ?

Comment: This is called a `join` and is a fundamental part of the SQL language.  If you are planning on using SQL, you should learn the basics.

Comment: Join both tables on group and fetch the name from first table.

Comment: You have columns called group and order. You should sneak around to the house of the person who created this and exact a terrible revenge. Break a gnome or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT stock_groups.name FROM stock_groups_styles_map, stock_groups WHERE stock_groups_styles_map.style ='N26';
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables, and select only the data you need. If you need unique rows, use the `distinct` keyword:

```
select  -- If you need unique names, use "select distinct" instead of "select"
    sg.name
from
    stock_groups_styles_map as sgs
    inner join stock_groups as sg on sgs.group = sg.group
where 
    sgs.style = 'N26'
```

You could also solve this using subqueries, but that would be rather inneficient in this case.

***Something important***

You should add the appropriate indexes to your tables. It will improve the performance of your database.

Comment: i get ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: @khinester, you are getting the collation error most probably cause both columns in both tables have different collation scheme. to solve this just change the `on` clause of `join` like `on sgs.group = sg.group collate utf8_general_ci`

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join on group column

```
SELECT ss.group, sg.name from 
stock_groups sg inner join stock_groups_styles_map ss on ss.group = sg.group 
where ss.style='N26'
```